# ASP.net core identity Yahoo email claim not received

Tags: asp.net-core-identity, yahoo-oauth

I am trying to use the Yahoo external OAUTH provider in ASP.Net Core Identity (nuget: AspNet.Security.OAuth.Yahoo) but it is not returning the email claim that I need. This is the configuration of the App in Yahoo:

[image: App permission configuration]

And this is how I configured the ASP.Net App:

```
 .AddYahoo(options =>
             {
                 options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Yahoo:ConsumerKey"];
                 options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Yahoo:ConsumerSecret"];
                 options.Scope.Add("email");
                 options.SaveTokens = true;
             })
```

All I am getting is one claim of type "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"

Please help.

Thanks.